# Why is React Native's NetInfo not being triggered properly when starting app w/o Internet?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, network-connection

I have a component to track the Internet connectivity of the device and display a small red banner when there is no connection. In general, it works properly: when you are in the app and you toggle your Internet, the banner appears and disappears.

However, if you **start the app with no Internet**, it **does not show the banner**. Once you turn Internet on, it will from then on will work properly.

---

Here is the component, `OfflineNotice.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NetInfo, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

interface State {
  isConnected: boolean;
}

export class OfflineNotice extends React.Component<any, State> {
  public state = {
    isConnected: true,
  };

  public handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected: boolean) => {
    if (isConnected !== this.state.isConnected) {
      console.log('isConnected', isConnected);
      this.setState({ isConnected });
    }
  };

  public componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  public componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  public render() {
    if (!this.state.isConnected) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.offlineText}>
            No Internet Connection
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a thought, is the event only ever triggered when there is a change in network? If so, then you may want to intialise the connection boolean as false. When you receive network, which fires the event off - it then should update the state?

Comment: Ah, of course! Good catch. Now it works. I love one-line fixes haha

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JRK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9941043/jrk) pointed out so quickly in his comment above, the solution is simple. Connection changes trigger the event, and when you start the app without Internet, there is no connection change.

If you **initialise** `isConnected` **in state as** `false`, the event will be fired when the connection is initiated.

The best way to do this is in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
    this.setState({isConnected});
  });
}
```

If you don't do this, but instead only set `isConnected` to `false` in `this.state` and add the event listener in `componentDidMount`, it will not work properly on Android. Props for the above to Terry Bazi from [a comment](https://medium.com/@bazine.tarik/as-guga-katsiashvili-said-isconnected-should-not-be-true-at-first-e3fa50fe5b3a) to a Medium article on this subject.

You can learn more in the examples in the React Native docs on NetInfo, especially the final section on the `isConnected` property: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo#properties-1

Comment: when i tried to do this, i got , TypeError: undefined is not an object

Comment: @SagarRS OK, this may be out of date at this point. I'll take a look and see if I can reproduce. Two questions: Is it referring to `NetInfo` being undefined? And what version of React Native are you using?